# Perl - How to open/change current Excel version with Win32::OLE

Tags: excel, perl

On my laptop I have 2 versions of Excel (64bit and 32bit). When I open Excel file as a standalone it opens the 32bit version and that is what I need.
But when I run my Perl script it opens Excel file with Excel 64bit version.

Snip of my code:

```perl
$excel = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application') ||  Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application') or die "CreateObject : +$!\n";
$excel->{Visible} = 1;
$excel->Workbooks->Open($f_excel->{full});
```

I need assistance to identify how Perl (Wn32::OLE::Const) package decides which version of of Excel to use.
When I check a path of created Excel object it says `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15` (this means 64 bit version).

Thank you.

Comment: *"When I check a path of created Excel object it says `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15`"* What is the path to the other 32 bit Excel version?

Comment: The path to the 32 bit version is : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16